# Connecting to X11 using Windows 10 OpenSSH and vcXsrv

Tags: windows, ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, openssh

In the last year, Microsoft began including [OpenSSH in Windows 10](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_overview).

I'm wondering, if it's possible to use OpenSSH (i.e. the `ssh` command in PowerShell) to connect to remote graphical applications on a Linux server, using [vcXsrv](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vcxsrv/) or something similar.

I've been able to find:

- Guides for how to connect to X applications using the 3rd party program PuTTY and vcXsrv
- Guide for how to connect X applications using Linux's `ssh` command from within WSL

However, I haven't found anything for how to get the Windows built-in ssh talking to X11. Is this possible?" Or will I have to go through WSL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible as long as you tell the 'ssh' client to use TCP for local X11 – that is, make sure your DISPLAY environment variable includes a hostname (`localhost`) in front of the display number.

For example, if your X display is `:0` (and vcXsrv is listening on port 6000), use:

```
PS> $env:DISPLAY = "localhost:0"
PS> ssh -Y host.example.com
```

(Many tutorials will talk about setting DISPLAY to just "`:0`", but this indicates that AF_UNIX sockets should be used, which makes sense on Unix-like systems but most likely won't be supported by Windows X servers.)

Comment: That did the trick, thanks so much! Does the DISPLAY variable need to be set each time, or should the setting persist?

Comment: Environment variables are process-level and only apply to that particular PowerShell window (and programs launched from it). You can place them in the Registry to be re-applied on every login (use the `setx` tool or see [this section](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables?view=powershell-7.1#saving-changes-to-environment-variables) about that). I assumed you had already set $DISPLAY to the wrong value in the same way.